# I have just changed my Apple ID, but made a typing error. No verification. Not searchable via find my Apple ID

Tags: apple-id

Just logged in to amend settings on my Apple ID. When entering new email, must have typed it wrong. Never received verification and now can't log back in.
Can't 'find Apple ID' as I don't know what my typo was.

How else can I retrieve it as am now logged out on all my devices.

Comment: I would try searching in the keychain access app for apple id or iCloud, or alternatively going to icloud.com and trying your old address which might still be connected.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. Have managed to retrieve and rectify my typo via keychain.phew!

Comment: cool. I'll add it as an answer... I wasn't sure it was a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Open Keychain Access which should be in Applications > Utilities and search for "apple id" and it should show you the email address you used.